# How to obtain/parse JSONObject data with GSON

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to use `retrofit` with `android`, which is kind of forcing me to use `gson`.

I am trying to get the data from the `payload["response"]["docs"][0]["web_url"]` in my code.

Issue : the key `getResponse()`, from below `model` class, always gives me `{}`. Whats the right way to handle this in android? Also note, the `getCopyright()` & `getStatus()` are working fine.

I am also providing the sample payload.

I have the `model` class like this :

```
public class ArticleSearchResponseModel {

    @SerializedName("status") private String status;
    @SerializedName("copyright") private String copyright;
    @SerializedName("response") private JSONObject response;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public String getCopyright() {
        return copyright;
    }

    public JSONObject getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public void setCopyright(String copyright) {
        this.copyright = copyright;
    }

    public void setResponse(JSONObject response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

}
```

My payload :

```
{
  "response": {
    "meta": {
      "hits": 15987906,
      "time": 108,
      "offset": 0
    },
    "docs": [
      {
        "web_url": "http://www.nytimes.com/2016/11/13/insider/gender-issues-in-sharp-focus-at-the-times.html",
        "snippet": "Susan Chira, senior correspondent for gender issues, and Susan Dominus, a Times Magazine writer, talk about men, women and coverage of their changing roles.",
        "lead_paragraph": "Susan Chira, senior correspondent for gender issues, and Susan Dominus, a Times Magazine writer, talk about men, women and coverage of their changing roles.",
        "abstract": null,
        "print_page": null,
        "blog": [],
        "source": "The New York Times",
        "multimedia": [
          {
            "width": 190,
            "url": "images/2016/10/14/insider/14-Insider-SUSANIMAGE/14-Insider-SUSANIMAGE-thumbWide.jpg",
            "height": 126,
            "subtype": "wide",
            "legacy": {
              "wide": "images/2016/10/14/insider/14-Insider-SUSANIMAGE/14-Insider-SUSANIMAGE-thumbWide.jpg",
              "wideheight": "126",
              "widewidth": "190"
            },
            "type": "image"
          },
          {
            "width": 600,
            "url": "images/2016/10/14/insider/14-Insider-SUSANIMAGE/14-Insider-SUSANIMAGE-articleLarge.jpg",
            "height": 400,
            "subtype": "xlarge",
            "legacy": {
              "xlargewidth": "600",
              "xlarge": "images/2016/10/14/insider/14-Insider-SUSANIMAGE/14-Insider-SUSANIMAGE-articleLarge.jpg",
              "xlargeheight": "400"
            },
            "type": "image"
          },
          {
            "width": 75,
            "url": "images/2016/10/14/insider/14-Insider-SUSANIMAGE/14-Insider-SUSANIMAGE-thumbStandard.jpg",
            "height": 75,
            "subtype": "thumbnail",
            "legacy": {
              "thumbnailheight": "75",
              "thumbnail": "images/2016/10/14/insider/14-Insider-SUSANIMAGE/14-Insider-SUSANIMAGE-thumbStandard.jpg",
              "thumbnailwidth": "75"
            },
            "type": "image"
          }
        ],
        "headline": {
          "main": "Gender Issues in Sharp Focus at The Times",
          "content_kicker": "Insider Podcasts",
          "kicker": "Insider Podcast"
        },
        "keywords": [
          {
            "rank": "1",
            "is_major": "N",
            "name": "subject",
            "value": "Presidential Election of 2016"
          },
          {
            "rank": "2",
            "is_major": "N",
            "name": "subject",
            "value": "Women and Girls"
          },
          {
            "rank": "3",
            "is_major": "N",
            "name": "subject",
            "value": "Gender"
          },
          {
            "rank": "4",
            "is_major": "N",
            "name": "subject",
            "value": "Men and Boys"
          },
          {
            "rank": "5",
            "is_major": "N",
            "name": "persons",
            "value": "Trump, Donald J"
          }
        ],
        "pub_date": "2016-11-13T00:00:00Z",
        "document_type": "article",
        "news_desk": "Insider",
        "section_name": "Times Insider",
        "subsection_name": null,
        "byline": {
          "person": [
            {
              "organization": "",
              "role": "reported",
              "firstname": "Susan",
              "rank": 1,
              "lastname": "LEHMAN"
            }
          ],
          "original": "By SUSAN LEHMAN"
        },
        "type_of_material": "News",
        "_id": "58011d9b253f0a0e44966174",
        "word_count": null,
        "slideshow_credits": null
      },
      {
        "web_url": "http://www.nytimes.com/2016/10/25/realestate/doors-of-manhattan.html",
        "snippet": "Even though they stand between us and the chaos of the city, the borough’s distinctive doors are easy to overlook.",
        "lead_paragraph": "Even though they stand between us and the chaos of the city, the borough’s distinctive doors are easy to overlook.",
        "abstract": null,
        "print_page": null,
        "blog": [],
        "source": "The New York Times",
        "multimedia": [],
        "headline": {
          "main": "Doors of Manhattan",
          "content_kicker": "Voyeur",
          "kicker": "Voyeur"
        },
        "keywords": [
          {
            "rank": "1",
            "is_major": "N",
            "name": "subject",
            "value": "Real Estate and Housing (Residential)"
          },
          {
            "rank": "2",
            "is_major": "N",
            "name": "subject",
            "value": "Architecture"
          },
          {
            "rank": "3",
            "is_major": "N",
            "name": "glocations",
            "value": "Upper West Side (Manhattan, NY)"
          },
          {
            "rank": "4",
            "is_major": "N",
            "name": "glocations",
            "value": "Upper East Side (Manhattan, NY)"
          }
        ],
        "pub_date": "2016-10-25T00:00:00Z",
        "document_type": "article",
        "news_desk": "RealEstate",
        "section_name": "Real Estate",
        "subsection_name": null,
        "byline": {
          "person": [
            {
              "firstname": "Photographs",
              "middlename": "George",
              "lastname": "ETHEREDGE",
              "rank": 1,
              "role": "reported",
              "organization": ""
            }
          ],
          "original": "Photographs by GEORGE ETHEREDGE for THE NEW YORK TIMES"
        },
        "type_of_material": "News",
        "_id": "57e94175253f0a6bb40cbffc",
        "word_count": null,
        "slideshow_credits": null
      },
      {
        "web_url": "http://cooking.nytimes.com/recipes/1018356-celery-toasts",
        "snippet": "This was the first recipe that the chef and writer Gabrielle Hamilton brought to The Times as an Eat columnist for the Sunday magazine in 2016, a snack-tray-sandwich version of a celery-and-fennel salad served at her restaurant, Prune, in the East...",
        "lead_paragraph": "This was the first recipe that the chef and writer Gabrielle Hamilton brought to The Times as an Eat columnist for the Sunday magazine in 2016, a snack-tray-sandwich version of a celery-and-fennel salad served at her restaurant, Prune, in the East Village. It calls for thick, white toasted Pullman bread spread wall to wall with unsalted butter, with slices of blue cheese neatly laid on top, below a mound of shaved celery and thinly sliced scallions dressed in garlic, olive oil, lemon juice and salt, and the whole shebang dusted in ground black pepper before being cut in halves or quarters. \"The ingredients come from the grocery store,\" she wrote in her column. \"These toasts are not expensive or intimidating, but they are outstanding.\"",
        "abstract": null,
        "print_page": null,
        "blog": [],
        "source": "du_recipe",
        "multimedia": [
          {
            "credit": "Davide Luciano for The New York Times. Food stylist: Michelle Gatton. Prop stylist: Alex Brannian.",
            "url": "images/2016/10/23/magazine/23eat/23eat-thumbStandard-v2.jpg",
            "rank": "1",
            "height": 75,
            "subtype": "thumbnail",
            "legacy": [],
            "caption": "Celery Toasts",
            "type": "image",
            "width": 75
          },
          {
            "credit": "Davide Luciano for The New York Times. Food stylist: Michelle Gatton. Prop stylist: Alex Brannian.",
            "url": "images/2016/10/23/magazine/23eat/23mag-23eat-t_CA1-articleLarge.jpg",
            "rank": "1",
            "height": 400,
            "subtype": "large",
            "legacy": [],
            "caption": "Celery Toasts",
            "type": "image",
            "width": 600
          }
        ],
        "headline": {
          "main": "A Snack Tray to Gather the Family Around",
          "name": "Celery Toasts"
        },
        "keywords": [],
        "pub_date": "2016-10-23T00:00:00Z",
        "document_type": "recipe",
        "news_desk": null,
        "section_name": null,
        "subsection_name": null,
        "byline": {
          "person": [
            {
              "organization": "",
              "role": "reported",
              "firstname": "Gabrielle",
              "rank": 1,
              "lastname": "Hamilton"
            }
          ],
          "original": "Gabrielle Hamilton"
        },
        "type_of_material": "Recipe",
        "_id": "580696f1253f0a7d028b0864",
        "word_count": "101",
        "slideshow_credits": null
      },
      {
        "web_url": "http://www.nytimes.com/2016/10/23/books/review/the-story-behind-this-weeks-best-sellers.html",
        "snippet": "Ruth Bader Ginsburg, whose anthology “My Own Words” is No. 12 in hardcover nonfiction, has something in common with Notorious B.I.G.",
        "lead_paragraph": "Ruth Bader Ginsburg, whose anthology “My Own Words” is No. 12 in hardcover nonfiction, has something in common with Notorious B.I.G.",
        "abstract": null,
        "print_page": "30",
        "blog": [],
        "source": "The New York Times",
        "multimedia": [
          {
            "width": 190,
            "url": "images/2016/10/23/books/review/23inside-list/23inside-list-thumbWide.jpg",
            "height": 126,
            "subtype": "wide",
            "legacy": {
              "wide": "images/2016/10/23/books/review/23inside-list/23inside-list-thumbWide.jpg",
              "wideheight": "126",
              "widewidth": "190"
            },
            "type": "image"
          },
          {
            "width": 75,
            "url": "images/2016/10/23/books/review/23inside-list/23inside-list-thumbStandard.jpg",
            "height": 75,
            "subtype": "thumbnail",
            "legacy": {
              "thumbnailheight": "75",
              "thumbnail": "images/2016/10/23/books/review/23inside-list/23inside-list-thumbStandard.jpg",
              "thumbnailwidth": "75"
            },
            "type": "image"
          }
        ],
        "headline": {
          "main": "The Story Behind This Week’s Best Sellers"
        },
        "keywords": [
          {
            "rank": "1",
            "is_major": "N",
            "name": "subject",
            "value": "Books and Literature"
          },
          {
            "rank": "2",
            "is_major": "N",
            "name": "persons",
            "value": "Ginsburg, Ruth Bader"
          }
        ],
        "pub_date": "2016-10-23T00:00:00Z",
        "document_type": "article",
        "news_desk": "BookReview",
        "section_name": "Books",
        "subsection_name": "Book Review",
        "byline": {
          "person": [
            {
              "organization": "",
              "role": "reported",
              "firstname": "Gregory",
              "rank": 1,
              "lastname": "COWLES"
            }
          ],
          "original": "By GREGORY COWLES"
        },
        "type_of_material": "News",
        "_id": "5800f337253f0a7985625011",
        "word_count": null,
        "slideshow_credits": null
      },
      {
        "web_url": "http://www.nytimes.com/2016/10/23/books/review/ngugi-wa-thiongo-birth-of-a-dream-weaver.html",
        "snippet": "A Kenyan considers his early years as a student and writer.",
        "lead_paragraph": "A Kenyan considers his early years as a student and writer.",
        "abstract": null,
        "print_page": "25",
        "blog": [],
        "source": "The New York Times",
        "multimedia": [
          {
            "width": 190,
            "url": "images/2016/10/23/books/review/23Wrong/23Wrong-thumbWide.jpg",
            "height": 126,
            "subtype": "wide",
            "legacy": {
              "wide": "images/2016/10/23/books/review/23Wrong/23Wrong-thumbWide.jpg",
              "wideheight": "126",
              "widewidth": "190"
            },
            "type": "image"
          },
          {
            "width": 600,
            "url": "images/2016/10/23/books/review/23Wrong/23Wrong-articleLarge.jpg",
            "height": 400,
            "subtype": "xlarge",
            "legacy": {
              "xlargewidth": "600",
              "xlarge": "images/2016/10/23/books/review/23Wrong/23Wrong-articleLarge.jpg",
              "xlargeheight": "400"
            },
            "type": "image"
          },
          {
            "width": 75,
            "url": "images/2016/10/23/books/review/23Wrong/23Wrong-thumbStandard.jpg",
            "height": 75,
            "subtype": "thumbnail",
            "legacy": {
              "thumbnailheight": "75",
              "thumbnail": "images/2016/10/23/books/review/23Wrong/23Wrong-thumbStandard.jpg",
              "thumbnailwidth": "75"
            },
            "type": "image"
          }
        ],
        "headline": {
          "main": "Ngugi wa Thiong’o on Starting Out as a Writer",
          "content_kicker": "Nonfiction",
          "kicker": "Nonfiction",
          "print_headline": "A Long Look Back"
        },
        "keywords": [
          {
            "rank": "2",
            "is_major": "N",
            "name": "persons",
            "value": "Thiong'o, Ngugi wa"
          },
          {
            "rank": "3",
            "is_major": "N",
            "name": "subject",
            "value": "Books and Literature"
          },
          {
            "rank": "4",
            "is_major": "N",
            "name": "subject",
            "value": "Writing and Writers"
          }
        ],
        "pub_date": "2016-10-23T00:00:00Z",
        "document_type": "article",
        "news_desk": "BookReview",
        "section_name": "Books",
        "subsection_name": "Book Review",
        "byline": {
          "person": [
            {
              "organization": "",
              "role": "reported",
              "firstname": "Michela",
              "rank": 1,
              "lastname": "WRONG"
            }
          ],
          "original": "By MICHELA WRONG"
        },
        "type_of_material": "Review",
        "_id": "57ff4d1d253f0a6b9720abd2",
        "word_count": null,
        "slideshow_credits": null
      },
      {
        "web_url": "http://cooking.nytimes.com/recipes/1018347-lemon-drizzle-cake",
        "snippet": "This light and moist lemon poundcake has a crunchy sugar glaze that crystallizes on top, giving a contrasting texture to the soft crumb underneath. It’s an easy-to-make, crowd-pleasing cake that’s excellent on its own but takes well to...",
        "lead_paragraph": "This light and moist lemon poundcake has a crunchy sugar glaze that crystallizes on top, giving a contrasting texture to the soft crumb underneath. It’s an easy-to-make, crowd-pleasing cake that’s excellent on its own but takes well to embellishments. A scoop of ice cream or sorbet, fruit compote and-or lemon curd are all wonderful alongside.",
        "abstract": null,
        "print_page": null,
        "blog": [],
        "source": "du_recipe",
        "multimedia": [
          {
            "credit": "Andrew Scrivani for The New York Times",
            "url": "images/2016/10/19/dining/19BAKEOFF2/19BAKEOFF2-thumbStandard.jpg",
            "rank": "1",
            "height": 75,
            "subtype": "thumbnail",
            "legacy": [],
            "type": "image",
            "width": 75
          },
          {
            "credit": "Andrew Scrivani for The New York Times",
            "url": "images/2016/10/19/dining/19BAKEOFF2/19BAKEOFF2-articleLarge.jpg",
            "rank": "1",
            "height": 400,
            "subtype": "large",
            "legacy": [],
            "type": "image",
            "width": 600
          }
        ],
        "headline": {
          "main": "‘The Great British Bake Off’ Changes the Way the British Bake",
          "name": "Lemon Drizzle Cake"
        },
        "keywords": [],
        "pub_date": "2016-10-19T00:00:00Z",
        "document_type": "recipe",
        "news_desk": null,
        "section_name": null,
        "subsection_name": null,
        "byline": {
          "person": [
            {
              "organization": "",
              "role": "reported",
              "firstname": "Melissa",
              "rank": 1,
              "lastname": "Clark"
            }
          ],
          "original": "Melissa Clark"
        },
        "type_of_material": "Recipe",
        "_id": "58066d7c253f0a7d028b07d0",
        "word_count": "250",
        "slideshow_credits": null
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": "OK",
  "copyright": "Copyright (c) 2013 The New York Times Company.  All Rights Reserved."
}
```

Comment: You have to use your own Object Model instead of `JSONObject` because the names of the fields/accessors are needed but `JSONObject` doesn't provide these.

Comment: You must not use Gson, just get `ResponseBody` and proceed with messy conversions and parsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before start, I'm not familiar with retrofit. 
If you want serialize/unserialize json to pojo, you better make pojo object.

```
class Response {
    Meta meta;
    List<Docs> docs;
}

class Docs {
    String webUrl;
    Mutimedia multimedia;
    ... 
}
```

The issue `the key getResponse(), from below model class, always gives me {}` happens because gson cannot determine proper object to convert json to plain old java object.

Comment: I think this `List` gave me the tip-off, thanks very much @Sung

Comment: and it works on `android` with `retrofit` now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your Response model class use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/.

[Making POJO simple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4egq.png)

Answer (score 1):

you no need to make exact structure in model
you can go ahead with your code just need small change

Use

```
@SerializedName("response") private JsonObject response;
```

instead of

```
@SerializedName("response") private JSONObject response;
```

and in the import

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
```